# Links longer than Images

Tags: image, html, hyperlink, overlap

So, I'm working on making a "links" div on my site. ([reference here)](http://music.papkeeproductions.com) The links are all images, but for some reason the div they are contained in is unnecessarily long. The images are supposed to be about three times as long as they are now, but whenever I resize the div to make them bigger it overlaps the video and pushes it down.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://music.papkeeproductions.com"><img src="Images/button_home.png" width="52%" height="69" style="width:15%;height:auto;" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://papkee.bandcamp.com"><img src="Images/button_music.png" style="width:15%;height:auto;" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://papkeeproductions.com"><img src="Images/button_films.png" style="width:15%;height:auto;" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="player">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MTmUnOHs5Xs"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.links {
float:left;
width:100%;
margin-left:0;
height:auto;
}
.links ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.links img {
width:180px;
height:auto;
}
.player {
float:right;
padding:8px;
border-style:solid;
border-radius:31px 31px;
border-color:rgb(45,25,11);
border-width:2px;
margin-right:0;
width:45%;
height:45%;
}
.player iframe {
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:none;
}
```

So whaddup with that? It's been rustling my jimmies all day and I can't seem to find the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style attributes located within the  tags are overriding the stylesheets:

```
style="width:15%;height:auto;"
```

Takes precedence over:

```
.links img {
    width:180px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh geez, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the width of .links at 100%, changing this to 30% keeps the video from pushing down.  Here's example of the change http://codepen.io/hwatkins/pen/qmzEB